# Contar registros si aparecen en otra tabla, si no colocar 0 en mysql

Tags: mysql

quiero contar los pacientes de cada representantes que están en un rango de fecha, y el representante que no tenga pacientes afiliados entre esa fecha, colocarles 0, actualmente tengo esto, tengo 3 tablas las cuales se unen con la foreng key TarjetaID y RepresentanteID

```
SELECT
R.*,
count(P.TarjetaID)
FROM representante R
LEFT JOIN tarjeta T ON T.RepresentanteID = R.RepresentanteID
LEFT JOIN paciente P on P.TarjetaID = T.TarjetaID
where P.PacFechaAfiliacion BETWEEN '2021-11-01' and '2021-11-30'
GROUP BY R.RepresentanteID
ORDER BY `R`.`RepresentanteID` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno esto fue lo que hice, puede que este mal optimizado ya que dura un poco, si alguien tiene una solucion mejor se lo agradeceria

```
SELECT
IFNULL(L.LineaDescripcion,'NINGUNO') LINEA,
r.RepEstatus ESTATUS, 
r.RepresentanteID , r.RepNombre, 
(SELECT COUNT(TarjetaID) FROM paciente p 
WHERE r.RepresentanteID = p.RepresentanteID and p.PacFechaAfiliacion BETWEEN '2021-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-11-30 23:59:59') CANT_PACIENTES,
(SELECT COUNT(v.TarjetaID) FROM venta v left join paciente p 
on p.TarjetaID = v.TarjetaID 
WHERE r.RepresentanteID = p.RepresentanteID
and p.PacFechaAfiliacion BETWEEN '2021-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-11-30 23:59:59') CON_COMPRA
FROM representante r
LEFT JOIN representante_linea RL ON RL.RepresentanteID = r.RepresentanteID
LEFT JOIN linea L ON L.LineaID = RL.LineaID
```